# thinktecture identity server auto login

Tags: autologin, thinktecture-ident-server

In project I'm working on we use IdentityServer which is identity server for lots of clients (mostly websites)
I have such problem:
1. User creates account using registration page that's within website X. 
2. After registration verification email is being sent. This link contains guid that is user specific and based on that I can get user data from user store
3. When clicking verification email user should be automaticaly logged in with IdentityServer.

Is it possible to perform step 3 using IdentityServer? If yes - could you give me some hints on how to do that?

Comment: What do you meant by auto login, without typing username,password or both?

Comment: Hello Michal, Did you manage to solve this problem? I have similar problem, where I want a new registered user to be logged in automatically after completing the registration process. Thanks.

Comment: hello michalito, did you resolve problem?